# Does masking a subfolder with .htaccess have a negative effect on SEO?

Tags: seo, htaccess, redirects, masking, subdirectory

My website is physically located at `example.com/websitedirectory`.

I am masking the folder so that the document root folder is redirected to `/websitedirectory` and the folder is masked, so that it displays as `example.com` from the outside.

Does this have any impact on SEO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume you mean that any request for `example.com/page.html` outputs the content of the file from `websitedirectory/page.html`. If it was "redirected" then the browser would show the subfolder in the URL.

In your case, there is no effect on SEO. Search engines will see the same URLs you see in your browser and won't know about the subdirectory unless you link directly to it.

One tiny thing to note: with your system it's likely that requesting the subdirectory page also works. In other words, loading `example.com/websitedirectory/page.html` gives the same content as `example.com/page.html`. This isn't an issue if no one knows about the subfolder (i.e. you don't link to it anywhere), but if the issue comes up it can be solved by using [rel=canonical](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en).

Incidentally, your site would be "physically" located at something like `/var/www/example.com/websitedirectory` on the server. Your host probably has it set so your domain points to the folder `/var/www/example.com`

If you have full server access then you should set up the "virtual host" to point to the subfolder, as that makes things simpler for yourself (but still makes no difference for SEO).

Comment: I don't have root access so I can't change the physical access. I expected it not having an effect (as I am using it on multiple sites and haven't noticed any issues) but wanted to know if I might have missed something. Will keep this question opened for a few more days to see if there is anything that I have missed.

Comment: I did forget to mention one tiny thing in my answer, which I have now added. But again, shouldn't make a difference.